# How to naturally convey the concept of sightseeing?

Tags: español-neutral

I am trying to convey the concept of sightseeing.

I have looked into this extensively. I have seen [some sources](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-say-Im-also-going-to-go-sightseeing-in-Spanish) say that Spanish doesn't have an exact term for sightseeing.

[Spanishdict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/sightseeing) lists turismo as the translation. However, this word is also used for tourism. So I am not sure if `turismo` is a good equivalent, as tourism usually has a subtle sense of commercial activity. For example, it might sound a little odd to consider to go hiking in the mountains as a form of tourism.

Searching through articles on Newspapers, I see "visita turística" used (Example [1](https://www.elnortedecastilla.es/palencia/velilla-presentara-gobierno-20200727112542-nt.html), [2](https://www.cope.es/emisoras/la-rioja/la-rioja-provincia/logrono/noticias/saborear-tierra-con-nombre-vino-20200802_834540), [3](https://byzness.elperiodico.com/es/tu-empleo/20200728/teletrabajo-nocturno-ventajas-jornada-vespertina-8057112))

So would `visita turística` be natural to use before naming an activity in a heading.

E.g.

```
Visita turística: Arquitectura (Sightseeing - Architecture)
Visita turística: Museo de Arte (Sightseeing - Art Museum)
Visita turística: Castillos (Sightseeing - Castles)
Visita turística: Iglesias (Sightseeing - Churches)
Visita turística: Atracciones en la ciudad (Sightseeing - City Attractions)
Visita turística: Tour de historia (Sightseeing - History Tour)
Visita turística: Tour de cine (Sightseeing - Movie Tour)
Visita turística: naturaleza (Sightseeing - Nature)
Visita turística: safari (Sightseeing - Safari)
Visita turística: Sea Safari (Sightseeing - Sea Safari)
Visita turística: tienda (Sightseeing - Shops)
Visita turística: Museo Espacial (Sightseeing - Space Museum)
Visita turística: volcán (Sightseeing - Volcano)
Visita turística: Museo de la guerra (Sightseeing - War Museum)
Visita turística: zoológico (Sightseeing - Zoos)
```

If not what would be a natural way to express it?

Comment: sightseeing is usually an activity engaged in by tourists. That's why visita turística works in many cases. However, what did you do today? We went sightseeing. would not be: visita turística.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the IATE<sup>1</sup> web about terminology for the European Union, you can find the [following result](https://iate.europa.eu/search/standard/result/1597670091697/1):

> **humanities (3611)** [SCIENCE]
>
> **en**
>     sightseeing tour
>     city tour
>
> **es**
>     visita turística
>     visita de la ciudad

The translation is marked as being reliable, and I can't find anything wrong with it, so "sightseeing tour" (or just "sightseeing") can be translated as "visita turística", at least in European Spanish. I don't know if the American Spanish is OK with this translation or if they prefer another expression.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> IATE ('**I**nter**a**ctive **T**erminology for **E**urope') is the EU's terminology database. It has been used in the EU institutions and agencies since summer 2004 for the collection, dissemination and management of EU-specific terminology.</sub>

Comment: Sure, but what about I went sightseeing today?

Answer (score 3):

For a formal or organized context, "visita turística" looks fine. It's hard to be precise when translating idiomatic expressions. When I used to travel in Latin America, people would ask me what I was doing, and I'd try to explain to them, and almost invariably they would conclude that "¡ah, estás conociendo!". That seemed to sum it up pretty well, so that's what I say now if I'm asked.

Comment: I disagree completely. Most European languages have idioms with equivalent meanings.

Comment: +1 In Chile, "andar conociendo" is the natural way we call this activity.